# Handle Exceptions from inside Hangfire

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, hangfire

I have a scenario, I am scheduling a BackgroundJob to run after some random seconds on application start. After the job is performed then I am again scheduling the same BackgroundJob to run after some random seconds and it goes on and never stops.

What I want is if any exception occurs in Hangfire during this continuous process I want to shut-down my asp.net core app.

for example, while this process is happening I stop the SQL Server. So hangfire giving this exception that is obvious

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>       at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection()
>       at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection[T](Func`2 func)
>       at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection.RemoveTimedOutServers(TimeSpan timeOut)
>       at Hangfire.Server.ServerWatchdog.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
>       at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)

So I don't know where to handle this exception, so that I can stop my application if this exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by checking is storage is attached to hangfire or not.

```
        try
        {
            IStorageConnection connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain where did you put this code? Is it in a JobFilter?

Comment: I had to check that on Http call to a controller so that I made IActionFilter middleware for that. Before every call to a controller, it will check. So in case DB is not attached I am stopping the application.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two choices:

1. `try catch` in your method you call with Hangfire
2. Use a `IElectStateFilter`, especially if you want to have the same behaviour for any Hangfire job

First option is pretty straightforward:

```
public void MyMethod() {
    try {
        //your code
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { 
        //stop application here
    }
}

BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyMethod());
```

Second option goes like this:

1. Create an attribute class:

   ```
   public class MyFilterAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter, IElectStateFilter 
   {
       public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
       {
           var failedState = context.CandidateState as FailedState;
           if (failedState != null)
           {
               //job has failed, stop application here
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register the filter:

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseFilter(new MyFilterAttribute());
   ```
3. Add the attribute to your method

   ```
   [MyFilter]
   public void MyMethod() {
       //your code
   }
   ```
4. Call your code as usual:

   ```
   BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyMethod());
   ```

See [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/extensibility/using-job-filters.html) regarding filters.

Comment: OnStateElection never getting hit when this exception occurred. And this exception occurs when I used to stop database.

Comment: I am using BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => MyMethod()); not BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyMethod());

Comment: @ДвυΒдкдя I forgot a step: registering the filter. See update (step 2) -- it is also in the doc link I provided :)

Comment: Yea I have also globally registered the filters. It never get hits any method in filter attribute class. Hangfire only prints the exception in console

Comment: Right, I took the example from the doc and removed unused interfaces but also removed (by mistake) `IServerFilter`. Also I checked in my code and the register function I use is different. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I am using the full attribute class from the docs you shared right. Because I am also using OnPerformed event. What I am saying is that when I am stoping sql server no method is getting fired in attribute class also OnStateElection event is also not getting fired. Hangfire only printing exception on the console.

Comment: That's strange, I don't understand why the event would not be fired especially if `OnPerformed` works. I use `OnStateElection` for other purposes without problem (although I don't use scheduling)

Comment: Maybe try `OnStateUnapplied` / `OnStateApplied`

Comment: OnStateUnapplied./OnStateApplied they are also not getting fired

I am stopping database means I am detaching database from hangfire so I think my exceptions are of some fatal.

Comment: If I don't stop database then all the events getting fired.

Answer (score 0):

If you register a custom IJobFilterProvider, you must include the GlobalFilters.Filters in the result of the GetFilters method. For example:

```
public virtual IEnumerable GetFilters(Job job)
{
    var result = GlobalJobFilters.Filters.AsEnumerable()
                 .Concat(new JobFilter[] {
                     new JobFilter(new QueueAttribute(GetQueueName(job)), 
                                   JobFilterScope.Method, null)
                 });
    return result;
}
```

That worked for me!