# How to get the exception details of a failed background job with Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire to fire off some background jobs, then I am checking their progress looking for failed jobs using:

```
IStorageConnection connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection();
JobData jobData = connection.GetJobData(jobId);

if (jobData.State == FailedState.StateName)
   // Some how get exception details
```

I would like to get the Exception thrown that caused the job to fail. (I am throwing `new Exception("test error")` in my job currently to test it out).

I can't seem to find any docs or examples on how I can get this information, is it possible?

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924624/handle-exceptions-from-inside-hangfire It has some suggestions. You could use a global job filter to deal with exceptions, but you wouldn't be able to retrieve them in the way you are suggesting (I don't think).

Comment: I have seen the filter suggestion on other questions yes. As you say it looks like it won't achieve what I want without then storing the failed context elsewhere to be fetched by the polling code I posted in the post. I may have found a solution after seeing this however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176494/12458578 It appears I could use the MonitoringApi to fetch the failed jobs and grab the one Iwith a matching jobId

Comment: Cool, if you sort it out post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176494/12458578) on another question which used the `GetMonitoringApi`, I was able to use it here to get the exception message like so:

```cs
if (jobData.State == FailedState.StateName)
{
    var failedJobsCount = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi()
        .FailedCount();

    var failedJob = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi()
        .FailedJobs(0, (int)failedJobsCount)
        .SingleOrDefault(j => j.Key == jobId);

    var exceptionMsg = failedJob.Value.ExceptionMessage;
}
```

This gives me the `"test error"` message that was thrown from my job. Success!